# Plugin to automatically convert characters

Tags: sublimetext2

I have this javascript file that starts like this:

```
document.write('\x3cscript\x3e\x3c/script\x3e\x3c!
```

I would like to know if there is a plugin for sublime text 2 that can automatically convert those characters to readable code.
I would also like to know how would i search for this operation in a search engine.

Thanks

Comment: What would you like to convert those characters to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to decode these Characters, this site https://github.com/dotzero/Sublime-Text-2-Plugins may be  a good starting point (Yeah, partially Russian, but its understandable anyway).

Look at the functionalities

"To Unicode Notation"
And
"From Unicode Notation"

They are coded in the file ST2-Converter/converter.py

I was not successfull installing this correctly, but maybe you have more luck - or more time ;)

Alternatively the Code in converter.py can be used to easily Copy&Paste a Plugin for yourself.